# Set class for custom builder

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have this custom builder which I would like to use for configuration:

```
RestClient client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                    .gatewayUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                    .token("d778dh")
                    .usernamePassword("petrov", "password2")
                    .build();
```

Custom builder:

```
public class RestClientBuilder {    ....

    public static RestClientBuilder builder() {
        return new RestClientBuilder();
    }

    public RestClientBuilder connectionTimeout(int milliseconds) {
        ReactorClientHttpConnector connector =
                new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options ->
                        options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000));

        return connector;
    }

    public RestClient build() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder != null ? sslContextBuilder.build() : null;
        return new RestClient(gatewayUrl.toString(), token, username, password, sslContext);
    }
}
```

I want to use this code to set custom timeout:

```
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector =
            new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options ->
                    options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```

How I can use this custom code with my builder? I tried the above example But I have to use Object Cast. Is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

`RestClient` and `RestClientBuilder` are not Spring classes, this is why those classes are not expecting a Spring WebFlux client connector to configure them.

You're probably looking for `WebClient` instead.